# Adding drop down for user logout

Tags: android, xml, drop-down-menu

I have an XML. At the top of the XML I places one text view and one image. In the place of text view I am setting logged user name and when button clicked the user logged out. But I want to change my layout. when I click on the logged user name I want to display a drop down with option change password, change username, logout etc... How can I do that? Please help me and save my day

Comment: If i use spinner it will display separetly but i want to get drop down if i click the textview which sets the user name into it

Comment: Please show your xml code...

Comment: This is my layout... http://ge.tt/4cs5Pz72/v/0?c i want to show the small drop downbox id username admin@admin.com is clicked with logout, change password, editprofile options

Comment: This is my layout http://ge.tt/4cs5Pz72/v/1?c

Comment: you can use `android:spinnerMode=dropdown` for the Spinner to show like a dropdown. Set `android:prompt` to the username and the options as your array..

Comment: is it possible to diaplay spinner if we click on the text view?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a `TextView`. Set the prompt of the spinner as the username and pass the list of actions as a string array. Then in the `ArrayAdapter` override `isEnabled` for every item so that they cannot be selected. Also set an `onClickListener` for the textView in the `getView` method of the adapter and carry out the logic based on position of the item clicked.